# How do I go about sorting this kind of object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my object

```
{
    "1MON": "1",
    "1TUE": "1",
    "2TUE": "2",
    "3WED": "3",
    "6FRI": "6"
}
```

I have been trying to search hoping to get an answer but no luck.

I want to use the values to sort it

The expected output is

```
{
    "1MON": "1",
    "1TUE": "1",
    "2TUE": "2",
    "3WED": "3"
}
```

and then later on, I want to loop on it to remove the values and create a string like `1MON1TUE2TUE3WED6FRI`. The reason why  i am doing this is that i want to add HTML classes like `class="class-1MON1TUE2TUE3WED6FRI"` and when i want to remove 1 slot in that class i will use `myClassAsString.replace(/1TUE/g, "")` please help me!

Comment: you should start implementing your code and come back if you are stuck... stackoverflow is not exactly a place where you ask work to be done for you

Comment: The code is up there, I thik mentioned what i need

Comment: Forklif, I tried putting it in an array and some are saying  that JavaScript Arrays do not support keys

Comment: Look at toastal's answer short and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` keys in JavaScript aren't sorted and you can never expect them to be. You need to convert to an `Array` for that behavior.

```
const x = { "1MON": "2", "1TUE": "1", "2TUE": "2", "3WED": "3", "6FRI": "6" }

Object.entries(x)
  .sort(([,a], [,b]) => a > b)
  .map(([y]) => y)
  .join("")
//=> "1MON1TUE12TUE3WED6FRI"
```

Comment: This answer sorts by keys, not values, but that may not matter?

Comment: You're right... the question wasn't very clear, but I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

For Sorting you can try like this.

1. Get All the properties of the Object using `Object.keys(obj);`
2. Sort Items in the array by using the Comparer callback function for strings.

```js
var obj = {"1MON":"1","1TUE":"1","2TUE":"2","3WED":"3","6FRI":"6"};
var allProperties = Object.keys(obj);
var sortedResult = allProperties.sort( (first, second) => first.localeCompare(second) );

console.log(sortedResult)
```